# ng-click="currentTpl='/inventory.html'" Inside ng-repeat not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-template

I have a menu list, in which when I do ng-repeat , it is not working, but without ng-repeat it is working.

```
<div class="reports_header_tabs_holder">
      <span ng-repeat="tab in filters.tabs" ng-class="{'active_tab': tab.href == filters.activeTab }">
      <a ng-click="currentTpl='/{{tab.href}}.html'" >{{tab.title}}</a>
      </span>
```

Viewability
            optimization
            inventory

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLC3g/254/)

Please read the comment and try accordingly,

```
<!-- if you comment the ng-repeat anchor, above line ( <a ng-click="currentTpl='/{{tab.href}}.html'" >{{tab.title}}</a> ), and uncomment the below anchors, it works, -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `ngRepeat` creates separate scope for each iteration. It means that clicking the link you are setting child scope property `currentTpl`, which doesn't affect parent one.. Simplest fix is to refer parent scope variable directly:

```
<span ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
     <a ng-click="$parent.currentTpl = '/' + tab.href + '.html'" >{{tab.title}}</a>
</span>
```

Another problem is that you should not use `{{` interpolation tags inside of `ngClick`, because this is an expression, you don't have to interpolate `tab.href` to get its value.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nLC3g/255/